# Forcing a while(true) loop to exit in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to trick test coverage calculation to work with while true loops. The coverage tools I am using consider test coverage to be lacking due to the while ending case is never executed. This is obviously a bug in the coverage calculation. However, I am trying to invent something that works until the coverage calculation gets fixed upstream, or at least until a suitable ignore comment is implemented.

The problematic code looks as follows. This works fine and tests work fine. However, I get the missing code coverage due to the while loop never exiting.

```
function* greetings1(): Generator<string, never, undefined> {
  while(true) {
    yield 'hello'
  }
}
```

I explored the idea of creating a constant `TRUE` that would let specially crafted tests to exit the loops by mocking the constant `TRUE` and replacing it with a `false` value that exists the loop. However, this gives me a type error `A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end point. ts(2534)`.

```
const TRUE: true = true
function* greetings2(): Generator<string, never, undefined> {
  while(TRUE) {
    yield 'hello'
  }
}
```

Is it possible to add an escape hatch for exiting the while true loop without having to sacrifice the types and result to casting the entire function body? I would be fine doing a tricky cast with the constant `TRUE` if needed.

I also tried some tricks using `break`. However, the coverage tool considers the use of `break` to be different from the condition becoming false, so that does not entirely solve my problem. Is there is a solution, it probably needs to be based making the while loop end naturally.

I posted a related question about a specific code coverage tool one year ago. See [Istanbul code coverage : Ignore else branch of a while true loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242625)

Comment: Why is "test coverage" a `typescript` thing?

Comment: @Andreas - The TypeScript part of this is that the workaround for the test tool issue fall afoul TypeScript's being unhappy with `never` on a generator that does, in fact, return.

Comment: I'm surprised that the test coverage tool is fooled by that `TRUE` constant. That combined with not seeming to properly understand generators makes me leery of the tool.

Comment: Since this is not a reproducible example, I will only give a guess: try `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the issue, but maybe you could throw after the while loop? It should at least convince Typescript that the function does not return.

Comment: @Andreas It is not. I posted a separate question about fixing the test coverage. I just provided it here as an explanation about why I need solutions for this obscure problem in the first place.

Comment: Move the generator in its own file and [exclude that file](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#selecting-files-for-coverage) in the code coverage report?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The test coverage tool is *not* fooled by the `TRUE` constant. However, the constant gives me a name that I can use to override the value for a duration of a special test that only attempts to reach the unreachable branch.

Comment: @cyberixae - Ah, got it. Good.

Comment: The main thing I am wondering are 1) Why is the literal stronger than a const no matter what way we define it? 2) Is there no way to cast the const to make it as strong as a literal? Essentially I would want to do `while(TRUE as literal true) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, that's a tricky problem. You have one tool that wants to see the loop possibly exit (the test coverage tool), and another that wants to see it never exit (TypeScript).

Sadly, in this particular case, I think your best bet is a `ts-expect-error` annotation:

```typescript
const TRUE: true = true;
// @ts-expect-error 2534
function* greetings2(): Generator<string, never, undefined> {
    while (TRUE) {
        yield "hello";
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBXApgNQIYBsUwLwwAoBKPAPhgFl0oALAOnnTABMQBbYmAHhgEYBuALAAoEQHoxMAAJQIAWmQAPAA7JgUBfHgh4MAEwBWAMwAWEQDNEYdQEtwAKhgBzeMmRQbYJxF7EAXDAA4shgyIxQOlzQ8J5OADQwoQBuYQlWzMjmnsjM5ADeIjBFMADuNDaYyIQIKBjYyMQkBcLFxQCeNsiYzDAARDRdmCC9Qi3FAL4i40A)

That tells TypeScript that you expect the code following it to give you that error and **only** that error, and it should ignore it. If the situation changes such that the code **doesn't** produce that error, or it produces some other error, TypeScript will complain, so it's much better than `@ts-ignore`.

I **really** don't like doing that (or type assertions, which it effectively is), but in this situation with the tool conflict, I don't think you get a lot of choice.

Comment: This solution disables the check. It does technically solve the problem. However, I could benefit from the check while writing the code to see my code does not accidentally terminate.

Comment: @cyberixae - Right. As I said, it's a tough one, because the tools conflict. This is a *very narrow* workaround for the problem that won't hide other unrelated errors, but yes, it will hide it if you unintentionally introduce a way the generator returns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something else that might work:

```js
const TRUE: true = true
function* greetings2(): Generator<string, never, undefined> {
  while(TRUE) {
    yield 'hello'
  }
  throw new Error("Unreachable");
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgJQKoFEBcMoCcCuBTGAXk1zwFgAoAMxzGCgEtwAqGAcyzz0bDYgCYAFAEoMAcTxg8WAIZQQWADzQsDXgBoYUgG7TNtACZ4qavAYB8MAN6UYMAO4ALBgBs8gxKmHXbdmAE8GPBcDGAByR2CXEDDfAF9fKEcsEHstPDSULBSsQQAiJDBOGWBHGQAjNzzhAG5KOKA)

Throwing an exception unconditionally after the loop should be enough to convince Typescript that the function never exits, and it will not affect the normal behavior of the program.

Whether your coverage tool likes it or not is another question I guess :)

Comment: This solution converts a type error into a runtime error. Before this change I get a type error for code that may unintentionally reach the end. After this change I get no type error. Instead the software crashes if execution somehow reaches the end. I would prefer having a type error over a runtime crash.

Comment: @cyberixae - Execution **can't** reach the end, full stop. It will never be a runtime error. `while (true)` (which is what `while (TRUE)` is) will never break. Yes, if you change your `TRUE` constant such that you break it, you'll get a runtime error. I don't think you can reasonably avoid that very, very minor issue with this solution (or the very, very minor issue with my solution). Fundamentally: The tools conflict, so any solution that involves not replacing the misbehaving test coverage tool will be necessarily second-best.